# Specifying .net Custom data provider in web.config file?

Tags: .net

I have created a custom data provider using System.Data.Common class
 and implementing the interfaces IDBConnection,IDBCommand etc and the provider name is "MysampleProvider"

Now I want to specify the provider in connection string of web.config? so that I can use own provider (MysampleProvider) instead of the .net data providers.

can anyone guide me on this? with a example?

looking forward to your replies?

Hi, I followed your instruction and did the changes as below ,still no success.My source is below

```
    <DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="CustomDataProvider"/>
      <add name="Custom Data Provider" invariant="CustomtDataProvider" description=".Net Framework Data Provider" type="CustomDataProvider, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

<connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};server=192.168.1.6;uid=root;database=Sample;port=3306;pwd=root79" providerName="CustomDataProvider.DBManager" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay it comes from configuration. I copied the below from the machine config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="system.data" type="System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactoriesConfigurationHandler, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
  </configSections>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have updated the code in the above question itself, can you help on that?

Comment: Hi,The control is not coming to the provider i have defined, but it is still using the Mysql driver dll. Also i am not getting any errors... can you help me on this...